# How to expand or reduce a polygon with geodjango?

Tags: django, polygon, geodjango

I got a model with field using the gis polygon field.

```
boundary = models.PolygonField()
```

As the requirement I need to allow the user to provide offset/tolerance value. How do I expand or shrink this polygon without doing the math myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do believe [Geometry.buffer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.GEOSGeometry.buffer) is what you are looking for.

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Polygon

poly = Polygon.from_bbox((0, 0, 5, 5))
poly.extent # (0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 5.0)
p2 = poly.buffer(1)
p2.extent #(-1.0, -1.0, 6.0, 6.0)
```

if you want to shrink it, use a negative value in the call to buffer

Comment: Thank you so much that is exactly what I am looking for. Do you know how I can set the unit on the buffer? Can I do something this poly.buffer(D(km=2))? I looked in the documentation and google around but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: If the buffering is going to be small distances, the rule of thumb that one degree of latitude and longitude is equal to 110 km maybe good enough (this is only true at the equator). If you need accurate measures, you will need to choose the correst SRID. the use of D is only possible in Geoquerysets. But I dare say that way might turn out to be a lot easier!

Comment: Thank you! I could not find it in the docs; buffer has typically a different meaning in my area ;-)